# How to bind the reference table in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am quite new with Linq to SQL and MVC but I follow the NerdDinner on ASP.NET site.

I have tables Tournaments and TournamentTypes which TournamentTypeID is a reference.

In my MVC Detail view page, I want to display the TournamentTypeName which is sitting under TournamentTypes object. How do I achieve this?

In model class:

```
public Tournament GetTournament(int id)
        {
            return db.Tournaments.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TournamentID == id);
        }
```

In the Detail View:

```
<p>
            TournamentID:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.TournamentID) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            TournamentTypeID:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.TournamentTypeID) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            CourseID:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.CourseID) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Name:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Name) %>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your entity assocations are setup, you should be able to do something like:

```
    <p>
        TournamentTypeName:
        <%= Html.Encode(Model.TournamentType.TournamentTypeName) %>
    </p>
```